# Case with multiple conditions

Tags: sql-server

I need to change returned value, from select statement, based on several conditions. I tried something like that:

```
,CASE i.DocValue
  WHEN 'F2' AND c.CondCode IN ('ZPR0','ZT10','Z305') THEN c.CondVal
  ELSE 0
END as Value
```

why it is not working and what is recommended way to do this ? 
There will be next several WHEN conditions.

Thank you

Answer (score 53, accepted):

```
,CASE WHEN i.DocValue ='F2' AND c.CondCode IN ('ZPR0','ZT10','Z305') THEN c.CondVal
  ELSE 0
END as Value
```

There are two types of `CASE` statement, **SIMPLE** and **SEARCHED**.

You cannot evaluate multiple expressions in a Simple case expression, which is what you were attempting to do.

```
-- Simple CASE expression: 
CASE input_expression 
     WHEN when_expression THEN result_expression [ ...n ] 
     [ ELSE else_result_expression ] 
END 
-- Searched CASE expression:
CASE
     WHEN Boolean_expression THEN result_expression [ ...n ] 
     [ ELSE else_result_expression ] 
END
```

Example of Simple CASE:

```
CASE x
  WHEN 'a' THEN 'b'
  WHEN 'c' THEN 'd'
  ELSE 'z'
END
```

Example of a Searched CASE:

```
CASE 
  WHEN x = 1 AND y = 2 THEN 'a'
  WHEN x = 2 AND y = 1 THEN 'b'
  ELSE 'z'
END
```

Further Reading: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181765.aspx

Answer (score 5):

You can write like this one too if you have multiple requirements:

```
CASE WHEN CITY='HYDERABAD' THEN       
 CASE WHEN AREA='BHILL' THEN PIN='12345'      
 WHEN AREA='DSNR' THEN PIN='67890'          
 ELSE '33333'          
 END           
END AS PIN_COD
```

Comment: you are right, nested case for complex condition works too :)